# How to check if both the properties are not defined in an array of objects using react?

Tags: reactjs

I want to display a message "no data available" if both the properties property1. and property2 is not defined in an array of objects.
Below is the data structure,

```
data = [
      { 
        attributes: [],
        info: '',
        meshes: [],
      }
      {
       attributes: [],
       info: '',
       meshes: [],
      }
       .....so on.... 
      ]
```

Currently i check for info empty or not defined something like below,

```
render = () => {
    return (
        {this.loading &&
            <div className="spinner"/>}
        {!this.data || (this.data && this.data.every((data.info) => 
        !data.info)) && 
            <div>No info available</div>}
        {this.data && this.data.some((data.info) => data.info) &&
            <div>info available</div>}
     );
 }
```

I want to check if attributes and info are empty or undefined then display no info available message.
Could someone help me with this? thanks.

Comment: Are you looking for a ternary operator? so `condition ? onTrue : onFalse` kinda thing? Cause from the code you are not checking 2 different properties as far as I can see

Comment: yes i want to check if both attributes and info empty for each object...how can i do it...attributes is an array again and info is just a string.